# How to add TS files to launch vue3 application in prod

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

**Current folder structure:**

```
/appname/server.js
/appname/package.json
```

**Current package.json**

```
"scripts": 
{
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "start": "node server.js",
},
```

I'd like to write serve.js using TS. I know how to do in a typical TS project, but i'm not able to do so when webpacks are involved. If I update tsconfig to `include` serve.ts the js file doesn't end up in the dist folder.

**Wanted folder structure:**

```
/appname/server.ts
/appname/package.json
```

**Wanted package.json**

```
"scripts": 
{
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
},
```

To make this even more complicated, the `dist` folder is needed to drive the application, so I rather not mess with it, putting server.js in a different folder is probably a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ts-node` to run `server.ts` directly:

1. Install [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) as a `devDependency`:

   ```sh
   npm i -D ts-node
   ```
2. Update your NPM script to use `ts-node` instead of `node`:

   ```js
   {
     "scripts": {
       "start": "ts-node server.ts"
     }
   }
   ```

Or you can avoid a `devDependency` with `npx ts-node`:

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx ts-node server.ts"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The idea is to serve.js in production not in dev. This answer seems to be answering how it can be done during development. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Ok. Why isn't this solution viable in production?

Comment: I think it could be used in production no problem. Would you think it's advisable to have its own tsconfig.js file? or use the default one that vue is using?

Comment: If the build options are the same, you could save yourself an extra config. Normally, I would separate them, since the build options for your app might not be necessary for the server script, or vice versa.